# Object Instantiation in c ++ with a protected constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, instantiation, static-constructor

I have this c++ class and I want to initialize an object of this type:

```
class MyClass

{
public:

   /**
     *  Creates an instance of this class.
     *  @return Pointer to the created object.
     */    
static MyClass * Create ();


protected:
    // Explicit protected Constructor 
    //and Copy-Constructor, use Create() to create an  instance of this object.
    MyClass();

}
```

To create an instance, I did this:

```
static MyClass * m_object = myClass.Create();
```

but I got those warnings and errors:

```
   warning C4832: token '.' is illegal after UDT 'MyClass'

   error C2275: 'MyClass' : illegal use of this type as an expression

   error C2228: left of '.Create' must have class/struct/union
```

How to instantiate properly this object?

Comment: where is `myClass` defined?

Comment: This is a 3D graphic library, the class is defined in a different namespace as mine. The ; exists already at the end of the class but forgot to copy it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, Static variables/methods are access using scope resolution (::) operator.

change your code to

```
static MyClass * m_object = MyClass::Create();
```

Answer (score 1):

To call static member you have to use class name instead of object name. Your object instantiation should be like this.

```
MyClass *m_object = MyClass::Create();
```

Comment: Sorry, By mistake i answered for java.